# Rails exception handling when submitting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, render

I want to know what is the best method to handle an exception that occurs when saving a model during a form submit. I am currently using a code snippet like this.

```
class Mycontroller
  def edit
    @customer = Customer.new
    @permissions = Hash.new
    @permissions['save'] = true
    @permissions['clear'] = true
    @permissions['some_other'] = false
  end

  def submit_handler
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.update_attributes!(params[:customer])
    redirect_to(:controller => 'XXXXXX', :action => 'edit', :id=>params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e    
    render :action => :edit, :id => params[:id]
  end
end
```

And here is my view named edit.html.erb

```
<% form_for :customer, :url => {:action =>"submit_handler", :id=>id} do |acc|%>
<%= render :partial => 'fields', :locals => { :acc => acc } %>  
<table align="center">
<tr align="center">
<% if @permissions['some_other'] == true %>
<td id='some_other' align="center"><%= submit_tag "Some other" %></td>
<%end%>
<% if @permissions['save'] == true %>
<td id='save'align="center"><%= submit_tag "Save" %></td>
<%end%>
<% if @permissions['clear'] == true %>
<td id='clear' align="center"><%= button_to "Clear", :action => :clear %></td>
<%end%>
</table>
<%end%>
```

My understanding about the above code snippet is that render method does not call the action 'edit' before calling the template 'edit'. I am passing an object(@permissions) from the action handler for 'edit' to the template 'edit'. Things work fine when I do a redirect to the edit action but not during render as the object(@permissions) that I have passed from the controller to the template is not available during render. Am I doing things right? Is this the Rails way to handle exceptions? If so, how can I pass an object(@permissions) to the template when I call render method? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the error happening? If you are naming the object `@customer` in the `edit` function and the view(form), you will not get the error, as `@customer` object is created in the `submit_handler` action also..

Comment: @rubyprince: I have edited the code to make it more clearer. Let me know if this helps to understand my problem. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is redundant:

```
@customer.update_attributes!(params[:customer])
@customer.save!
```

`update_attributes` will also save, so the call to `save!` isn't doing anything.  The more idiomatic way to do it in rails is like this:

```
def submit_handler
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

  # Update your attributes
  if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
    # Redirect on success
    redirect_to(:controller => 'XXXXXX', :action => 'edit', :id=>params[:id])
  else
    # Render the action template -- no need to reset the ID here
   render :action => :edit
  end
end
```

Is there some reason you need to be raising an exception when the save can't complete?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in adding the @customer.save!. Its actually not there in the original code. The actual code is a lot more complex one. The form contains several models and all are saved in a single transaction. I tried to give a simplified version of my problem. With the transaction logic in the controller I guess my only way is to raise an exception. Is there any way to pass the @permission object to the template??

Comment: If you want to pass the `@permissions` object back to the view in your `else` condition, you'll need to rebuild it (as it no longer exists as an instance variable on your controller).  There are several ways to do this.  Personally, unless those fields require some extra security, I'd just store them off as `hidden_field_tag`s and then reset the value in the `else` block.  Otherwise, you could stash them away in `session`.

Comment: Also, if you're saving multiple objects, you might want to check out some of the Railscasts that cover this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `save!` and `update_attributes!` methods and these methods will raise an ActiveRecord exception if any of the validations fail. Also your code is redundant in doing `update_attributes!` and `save!`. You are better to write this methods in the traditional scaffold way.

```
class Mycontroller
  def submit_handler
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])        
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      redirect_to(:controller => 'XXXXXX', :action => 'edit', :id=>params[:id])
    else
      get_edit_permissions()    
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end

  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    get_edit_permissions()
  end

  def get_edit_permissions
    @permissions = Hash.new
    @permissions['save'] = true
    @permissions['clear'] = true
    @permissions['some_other'] = false
    # @permissions = {'save' => true, 'clear' => true, 'some_other' => false}
  end
end
```

Actually you can make your life easier by declaring `customer` as a resource in the routes.rb(`map.resources :customer` in Rails 2.3.5) and naming the `submit_handler` method to `create` as this will follow the restful routing as advocated by Rails.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in adding the @customer.save!. Its actually not there in the original code. The actual code is a lot more complex one. The form contains several models and all are saved in a single transaction. I tried to give a simplified version of my problem. With the transaction logic in the controller I guess my only way is to raise an exception. Is there any way to pass the @permission object to the template??

Comment: as @jerhinesmith said, you will have to recreate variables used in `edit` rebuild in the `submit_handler` action also. You can make this a seperate method and call it in both `edit` and `submit_handler`. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for info about how to rescue exceptions raised in controller actions:
http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from